# how to check if there is "no route to host" over and over during streaming a video?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming

I know that I should use `setInterval(function(), time_interval_ms)`, but I don't know how to write the `function()` to check if there is a route to host!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that pings your host using AJAX. If the AJAX call was successful, your host is available; if not, your host is unavailable. You then use `setInterval` to call this "ping" method.

### Here is an example of this:

```
var timerDuration = 1000;
var hostUrl = "/your_url_to_ping.php";
var isAvailable = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        pingServer();
    }, timerDuration);
});

function updateStatus() {
    var o = $('#df');
    o.text('Is Available: ' + isAvailable);
}

function pingServer() {
    isAvailable = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: hostUrl,
        success: function(data) {
            isAvailable = true;
        },
        error: function() {
            isAvailable = false;
        },
        complete: function() {
            updateStatus();
        }
    });
}
```

[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pauloosthuysen/qFdzQ/5/)

### And here are guides you might require:

jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Cross-domain AJAX: http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide